# Acumatica Mobile: Remove redundant step in navigation

Tags: c#, acumatica

All,

I have mobile screen code:

```
<sm:Screen xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       DisplayName="Superannuation" 
       Id="MPES3013" 
       Icon="system://Credit"         
       Type="SimpleScreen"
       OpenAs="Form">

  <sm:Container Name="SuperannuationDetails" 
                FieldsToShow="3" 
                DisplayName="Superannuation Details" 
                >
    <sm:Attachments Disabled="true"/>
    <sm:Field Name="FundName" ForceIsDisabled="true" />
    <sm:Field Name="ContributionType" ForceIsDisabled="true"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Category"  ForceIsDisabled="true" />
    <sm:Field Name="MemberID" ForceIsDisabled="true"/>
    <sm:Field Name="CalculationMethod" ForceIsDisabled="true"/>
    <sm:Field Name="Value" ForceIsDisabled="true"/>
    <sm:Field Name="ESCTRate" ForceIsDisabled="true"/>
  </sm:Container>
  <sm:Container Name="EmployeeInfoEmployeeCode" FormActionsToExpand="1">
  </sm:Container>
</sm:Screen>
```

This code allows me to navigate to required data in 2 clicks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I remove superannuation second screen and navigate directly into 3rd screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the grid in 'expanded' state, try removing `openAs="Form"` and change `Type` to `FilterListScreen`, i. e.

```xml
<sm:Screen xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       DisplayName="Superannuation" 
       Id="MPES3013" 
       Icon="system://Credit"         
       Type="FilterListScreen">
  ...
</sm:Screen>
```

Also, you might want to add field(s) to primary container, so that user could change filtering criteria.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan! This is the only thing I needed to change.
I tried to find documentation about definition of these attributes for mobile, but I could not. For instance, attributes for sm:Field, sm:Screen, what kind of type do we have etc. Could you recommend such documentation?
There is no required information here:
https://adn.acumatica.com/content/uploads/2018/03/2018R1-AcumaticaFramework_DevelopmentGuide.pdf

Comment: See **Mobile Site Map Reference** in referenced doc, this is the best documentation available.

Answer (score 0):

You have a master detail relationship setup where `OpenAs="Form"` defines the master and `Container Name="SuperannuationDetails"` defines the details. This is similar to the FormGrid template used for web pages except that form and grid section are displayed as separate screen on mobile.

The mobile opens the first screen so you can select the master document. Once the master document is selected, it will open the details screen associated to the selected master document.

It seems you don't want the master document but only details. For Acumatica screen, such a pattern would be the `Grid` template instead of the `FormGrid`. If you create the mobile screen from a web page make sure that page uses the `Grid` template (only 1 grid visible on page, no form header).

Comment: Hi,
If I understand you correctly, I need to create a web page (aspx), that uses template "ListView". Right?
Do I also need to change the mobile page definition from OpenAs="Form" to something else?

Comment: I have a similar page:
<sm:Screen DisplayName="Payslips" Id="MPES3014" Icon="system://Box1" Type="SimpleScreen" IsDefaultFavorite="true" xmlns:sm="http://acumatica.com/mobilesitemap" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sm:Container Name="PayHistory" FormActionsToExpand="1" >
  <sm:Attachments Disabled="true"/>
 
  <sm:Field Name="PayDate" ForceIsDisabled="true" />
 </sm:Container>
</sm:Screen>
That behaves exactly what I need, and its web page does not have only grid. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Notice that it doesn't declare OpenAs="Form". My point is that the mobile screen is declared as being master-detail/form-grid and that's exactly what you don't want so that's likely a big part of the issue. There is another option of OpenAs="List" but I haven't found a single example using it and have not enough time to setup and test everything so I couldn't comment on it. The template for aspx pages in Acumatica I think is called Grid not  ListView.

Comment: Check page 260 of this document for the mobile ListView layout: https://adn.acumatica.com/content/uploads/2018/03/2018R1-AcumaticaFramework_DevelopmentGuide.pdf

Comment: I applied OpenAs="List", that does not show the redundant step, but now the screen is empty and there is no record in the list.